# Firebase : The method 'getCredential' isn't defined for the type 'GoogleAuthProvider'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i have the following problem. i'm new in flutter and firebase, how i can fix it. thanks

```
void _handleFirebase() async {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await _currentUser.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);

final FirebaseUser firebaseUser =
    await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

if (firebaseUser != null) {
  print('Login');
}
```

and the problem show

The method 'getCredential' isn't defined for the type 'GoogleAuthProvider'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getCredential'.

here is my  pubspec.yaml

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.0
  firebase_database: ^6.1.0
  rflutter_alert: ^1.1.0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getCredential` is deprecated. You should use `credential`.

```
GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
   idToken: googleAuth.idToken, 
   accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
);
```